# finding the equation of a cubic function with 2 points

Tags: functions, cubics

A cubic function is in the form $y=kx^3+c$. Find the equation if it passes through $(0,5)$ and $(2,-3)$.

I’m not sure how i would work this out algebraically or if i even can without graphing.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting place would be to use the given points to get relations between $k$ and $c$.

Comment: @lulu i’m not entirely sure how to find the relations between k and c

Comment: Well, what does it mean to say that $(x,y)=(0,5)$ satisfies the cubic equation?

Comment: @lulu i would assume so, yea. the question’s aim is to just find the equation of the function based on the standard function, y=kx^3+c

Comment: Can you solve two linear simultaneous equations? Substitute your numbers in and that's what you have

Comment: Ok...so what does it mean to say that $(x,y)=(0,5)$ is on the curve $y=kx^3+c$?

Comment: @Paul the substitution method worked, thank you

Comment: @lulu sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c=5,k=-1
Just plug in the values of the first point and the second point, solve the first equation for c, solve the second equation for k(with c=5). And you have your function y = - x³ + 5

Answer (score 1):

It passes through $(0,5)$, right? The first number in that pair is the value of $x$ and the corresponding value of $y$. So when $x=0$, $y=5$. Substitute it into your equation: $5=0+c$. It must hold since it passes through $(0,5)$. Hence you can conclude that $c=5$. Proceed further for the other point yourself.